# php_mail - receive the email twice - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need your advice / help on something that is driving me crazy. I always use ultimate members and want the admin to receive an email when a user has encountered their profile. The problem is that I receive the email twice ...

I added in the function.php file:

Sending an email after updating the user profile

```
add_action( 'um_user_after_updating_profile', 'profile_update_name', 1, 10 ); 

function profile_update_name() {

  $first_name = um_profile('first_name'); 
  $last_name = um_profile('last_name');

  $admin_email = "mymail@gmail.com"; 
  $message .= sprintf( __( $first_name .' '. $last_name . 'a mis à jour sa fiche de individuelle.')). "\r\n\r\n";

  wp_mail( $admin_email, sprintf( __( '[Modification fiche individuelle]' ) ),$message ); 

};
```